# Does this monoid have a name?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, semigroups-and-monoids, lattice-theory, posets

Fix a positive integer $n \geq 1$. Let $M$ be the monoid with generators $S=\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and relations $R = \{ \alpha x_0 = \beta x_0\colon \alpha,\beta \in S^*, |\alpha|=|\beta|\}$, where $|\alpha|$ is the length of a word $\alpha \in S^*$.

**Question**: Does this monoid have a standard name? Has it appeared somewhere?

It is very simple, so maybe not so interesting from the point of view of monoid theory.

But, for what it's worth, I'm interested in $M$ since it is the easiest example of a monoid with:

- $M$ is finitely generated, with homogeneous defining relations;
- $M$ is (left) cancellative;
- any two $x,y \in M$ have a least common (right) multiple.

This means that if $\leq_L$ denotes left divisibility, then $(M,\leq_L)$ is a lattice with the fractal-like property that every principal order filter in the lattice is isomorphic to the original lattice. (This property of a poset has been coined "upper homogeneous," or "upho," by Richard Stanley.)

**EDIT**: As Benjamin Steinberg points out in the comments, we can instead use the much smaller set of relations $R = \{x_0^2 = x_1x_0=\cdots= x_nx_0\}$.

**EDIT 2**: More generally, for any $r \geq 1$, we can consider the monoid $M=\langle S \mid R \rangle$ with $S = \{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $R = \{ x_0^{r+1} = x_1 x_0^r = \cdots = x_n x_0^r\}$ (so $r=1$ is the case above). It will have the same properties in the bullet list above.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the presentation $ax_0=bx_0$ for all generators a,b?

Comment: You can show by induction on length that $\alpha x_0=\beta x_0$ for $|\alpha|=|\beta|$ by replacing the suffix of length one smaller by a bunch of $x_0$'s

Comment: Change aax_0 to ax_0x_0 to x_0x_0x_0 and the same with the others

Comment: Basically the normal form is to change everything to the left of the last x_0 to x_0. Or did you not want to allow  alpha and beta to have x_0

Comment: Basically your monoid consists of pairs (n,x) with n a nonnegative integer and x in the free monoid on S-{x_0}.  Multiplication is (n,x)(k,y)=(n,xy) if k=0 and (n+|x|+k,y) if k>0.  Here (n,x) represents n x_0's followed by x

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Yes, that description looks right to me. Still, I wonder if it has a name, or belongs to some known class.

Comment: It belongs to the class of monoids with a quadratic presentation.  But not all of these have the propertied you want.

Comment: I don't know a name for this monoid in particular.  You can of course just use the relations ax_0=x_0x_0.  Maybe Google will say something

Comment: Any left cancellative monoid with right lcms and right gcds will give an upho for left divisibility

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: yes, that is the impetus for this investigation. I understand there are sophisticated examples of these from Garside theory. I was just trying to see what the simplest ones I could cook up by hand were first, though. (Incidentally -- at least if we use homogeneous relations -- I don't think gcds are an issue, all that matters are lcms.)

Comment: If each element has only finitely many left divisors, as is the case with homogenous presentations, then right lcms give right gcds.

Comment: Right lcms is a fairly difficult condition.  More common is where elements either  have a right lcm or no common right  multiples

Comment: What is the rank generating function of this poset (or length generating function of this monoid)?

Comment: @RichardStanley: it is $((1-x)(1-nx))^{-1}$. There are many ways to see this. For instance, it is clear from Benjamin's description of the monoid in terms of pairs $(k,y)$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}^*$. But also, in general any upho lattice has a rank generating function which is the inverse of the (reciprocal) characteristic polynomial of the interval from the minimum to the join of atoms, which in this case is the rank two modular lattice with $n+1$ atoms. Although note that this upho lattice is *not* modular.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: I see. So your poset is a direct product of a chain and a complete $n$-ary tree.

Comment: @RichardStanley: no, I don't think so. For one thing, the direct product of a chain and a tree will not be a lattice, right? But also, I believe this poset is indecomposable. You can also construct it as follows: start with a single element at rank $0$; then to recursively make rank $i+1$ from rank $i$, for each element in rank $i$ we add $n-1$ elements in rank $i+1$ covering that element, and then we also add one extra element in rank $i+1$ simultaneously covering all elements in rank $i$.

Comment: (k,y) left divides (m,x) iff m=k and y is a prefix of x, or $m\geq k+|y|$

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I think it should be “$m > k + |y|$” (strict inequality), but yes.

Comment: Yes you are right